# PHP regex, where did i go wrong?

Tags: php, regex

I'm new to regex, i have attempted a preg_match and the result should display `hello`, which doesn't happen.

```
$action3 = "(414)-4204";

if(preg_match('%^(\d{3})+-\d{4}$%',$action3)) {
echo "hello";
} else {
echo "goodbye";
}
```

Where did i go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the parentheses with backslashes. They are special characters in Regex.

```
preg_match('%^\(\d{3}\)+-\d{4}$%',$action3)
```